# Data type mismatch in VB 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

Good day guys, I have a question. When I try to use this piece of code in my program which will add a supplier to the database, I encounter data type mismatch error. As far as I know, the status of the supplier creates the error.

How would I store the values of the radio buttons named `radActive` and `radInactive` in the database? Should I use `Boolean` or a `String`? I am using Microsoft Access as my database and the field of `Status` is set to `Yes/No`.

Here's the code.

```
Public Sub SupplierInsertData()

    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Dim SupplierType As String
    Dim Status As Boolean

    'Check for supplier type
    If frmDatabaseSupplier.radLocal.Checked = True Then

        SupplierType = "Local"

    ElseIf frmDatabaseSupplier.radForeign.Checked = True Then

        SupplierType = "Foreign"

    End If

    'Check for supplier status
    If frmDatabaseSupplier.radActive.Checked = True Then

        Status = True

    ElseIf frmDatabaseSupplier.radInactive.Checked = True Then

        Status = False

    End If

    'For inserting of data in the database.
    Dim cmdString As String = "INSERT INTO Supplier(SupplierLastName, SupplierFirstName, SupplierMiddleInitial, " & _
                              "SupplierCompany, SupplierType, SupplierStreetAddress, SupplierCity, SupplierContactNumber, SupplierEmail, " & _
                              "Status)" & _
                              "VALUES('" & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierLastName.Text & "','" & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierFirstName.Text & "','" & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierMiddleInitial.Text & "','" _
                              & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierCompany.Text & "','" & SupplierType & "', '" & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierStreetAddress.Text & "','" & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierCity.Text & "','" _
                              & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierContactNumber.Text & "','" & frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierEmail.Text & "','" & Status & "')"

    conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ProjectAnalysisSystem.accdb")

    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should not be trying to resolve the type mismatch error. You should resolve the [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936254/sql-injection) issue. As soon as you are using [parametrized statements](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000275.html), the type mismatch error will solve itself.

Comment: But I think security is not yet an issue for now. I am still concentrating on the functionality first before everything else. I'll try to study about those things while I am creating the information system. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the last part of your code.
You should use parameters to pass the values of your textbox or vars to the database engine.
And don't forget to encapsulate the disposable objects like OleDbConnection in a `using` statement.

```
Dim cmdString As String = "INSERT INTO Supplier(SupplierLastName, SupplierFirstName, SupplierMiddleInitial, " & _ 
                          "SupplierCompany, SupplierType, SupplierStreetAddress, SupplierCity, SupplierContactNumber, SupplierEmail, " & _ 
                          "Status)" & _ 
                          "VALUES(@supplierName, @supplierFirst, @supplierMiddle, @supplierCo, @supplierType, @supplierStreet, @supplierCity, " & _
                          "@supplierContact, @supplierMail, @status)"
Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ProjectAnalysisSystem.accdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierName", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierLastName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierFirst", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierFirstName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierMiddle", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierMiddleInitial.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierCo", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierCompany.Text )
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierType", SupplierType)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierStreet", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierStreetAddress.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierCity", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierCity.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierContact", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierContactNumber.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierMail", frmDatabaseSupplier.txtSupplierEmail.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", Status) '<- Here the status var is correctly identified as a boolean, not as a string
    conn.Open() 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End Using
```

Comment: cmd.AddWithValue lacks the Parameters in the syntax. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue. Correct me if I'm wrong. :))

Comment: OleDb provider does not support named parameters.  You need to use a question mark in place of the parameter names in your query.  Be sure to add the parameters in the same order.

Comment: @Ju-chan you are right, forget the Parameters collection. Corrected

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It's true that the NET OleDb provider does not support named parameters, but with ACE and before that JET.OLEDB provider you could use also the named parameter syntax. It's important to add the parameters in the same order in which they appear in the sql string

Comment: Thanks for all of your opinions :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a data type mismatch error because your `INSERT statement` attempts to store a string value for the `Status` field whose data type is Yes/No.

This isn't really a VB.Net problem.  You would get the very same error from Access' db engine if you were attempting the same thing from VBA.  This is the output from the VBA procedure below.

```
INSERT INTO Supplier (Status)
VALUES('True')
Error -2147217913 (Data type mismatch in criteria expression.)
```

The procedure ...

```
Public Sub Ju_chan()
    Dim cmdString As String
    Dim Status As Boolean
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Status = True
    cmdString = "INSERT INTO Supplier (Status)" & vbCrLf & _
        "VALUES('" & Status & "')"
    Debug.Print cmdString
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute cmdString

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ")"
    Debug.Print strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

Please understand this is not intended to steer you away from using parameters.  I only wanted to clarify why you're getting that error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me an idea there :)